# Need to escape Special Characters in Java Web Application

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, encoding

I am working on a Java EE application with an Oracle DB. 
Now some content on the webpage has some special characters and I need to escape them.
The characters are coming as show below:

```
€˜Tâ€™ ! â€œOne Chase.â€ $ % & ( ) ' / : ? ` â€” â€“ _ â€š " Test
```

Is anyone aware what character encoding this is and how can I escape them? I need to escape them and replace them with a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Those characters are a side-effect of code that doesn't handle encodings correctly (something is assuming UTF-8 is ISO-8859-1, or vice versa) - they are junk at the moment. You need to fix your app to render them correctly. There is no need to replace them with blanks or do any filtering.

Read this article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html then check your database interactions, and your JSP and application server settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can pattern match the string and either build a black list of invalid characters or have a white list of valid characters....something like the following

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(blackList); // or reverse with a white list
 Matcher m = p.matcher(unsafeInputString);
 if (m.matches())
{
    // Invalid input: reject it, or remove/change the offending characters.
}
else
{
   // Valid input.
}
```

Comment: these are unicode characters...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters